# "Bad data" Exception when trying to decrypt a string

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to find out the reason i am getting a "Bad Data" exception when i try and decrypt a string. it works when i pull the key string from a text box

example: string key = textbox1.text.tostring();

but it doesn't work when i just put the key into the code manually as shown in the attached picture.

example: string key = "Test"

It works fine for encryption both ways but not for decryption

[Error showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVCTC.png)

Doesnt work.

```
 private void decrypt(string input)
    {
        string key = "test";
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] byteHash;
        byte[] byteBuff;

        byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        desCryptoProvider.Key = byteHash;
        desCryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
        byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        string plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(desCryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
        InputText.Text = plaintext;

    }
```

Does work.

```
  private void decrypt(string input, string key)
    {

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] byteHash;
        byte[] byteBuff;

        byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        desCryptoProvider.Key = byteHash;
        desCryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
        byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        string plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(desCryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
        InputText.Text = plaintext;

    }
```

Comment: Please include sufficient details *in the question as text* to re-create.

Comment: Hi ive included everything i can now sorry

Comment: Unless you also show us the call of Decrypt(string, string) so we can see what key you use in that case, we can not really start figuring it out. Even your written question has once "test" and once "Test", wich are totally different strings.

Comment: Just an observation - You don't have to call ToString() on a string.

Comment: **Do not use 3DES for new work**, it is not as secure as AES and only has 112-bit security with a triple key, instead use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) which supports key sizes of 128,192 and 256 bits.